# Inverse problem of a dyadic product (tensor product)

Tags: tensor-products

If we have two vectors, $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{n}$ , in 2D, where $\boldsymbol{n}$  is a normal vector:
$$
\boldsymbol{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
  v_1\\
  v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\boldsymbol{n} = \begin{bmatrix}
  n_1\\
  n_2\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $\boldsymbol{n} \ne 0$, but $n_1$ or $n_2$ could be equal to zero.The dyadic product of the two vectors:
$$
\boldsymbol{v} \otimes \boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{W} 
$$

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  v_1\\
  v_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  n_1 & n_2
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
  v_1 n_1 & v_1 n_2\\
  v_2 n_1 & v_2 n_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If I know $\boldsymbol{n}$  and $\boldsymbol{W}$ , how to calculate $\boldsymbol{v}$

Thank you in advance.

Edited:
I have thought of solving the for $\boldsymbol{v}$ as an overdetermined system of equations, something like:
$$
 \boldsymbol{W} \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{n}
$$
and then use the Least Squares technique to solve it:
$$
 \boldsymbol{v} = (\boldsymbol{W}^T \boldsymbol{W})^{-1} \boldsymbol{W}^T \boldsymbol{n}
$$
However, I'm not sure how to put ($\boldsymbol{v} \otimes \boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{W} $ ) in this form ( $\boldsymbol{W} \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{n}$).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some attempt.

Comment: You should probably add the condition that $n \ne 0$, because in that case, for *any* $v$ you get $W = 0$, so $v$ cannot be determined from $n$ and $W$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, $n \ne 0$, but $n_1$ or $n_2$ could be equal to zero.

Comment: @AnneBauval, I apologize for not showing my attempts earlier. I've thought of solving it as an overdetermined system of equations. Please take a second look at my question after the editing. Thank you!

Comment: @AnneBauval The solution of an overdetermined system is possible in a usual system of linear equations that has a combination of two vectors and one matrix. But how to manipulate the system that arises from a tensor product?
could you please share any references?

Comment: Instead of that edit "$\boldsymbol{W} \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{n}$" out of the blue, why don't you simply prove that there is a solution $v$ iff $$W_{1,1}n_2=W_{1,2}n_1\text{ and }W_{2,1}n_2=W_{2,2}n_1,$$ and calculate this (unique) solution $v$ in each of the two cases ($n_1\ne0$ or $n_2\ne0$)?

Comment: Do you still need help? What don't you understand in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4812805/timeline#comment_10239823)? My feeling was that with little work, you could have found it yourself.

Comment: Your answer  $ \boldsymbol{v} = \frac{1}{||\boldsymbol{n}||^2} \boldsymbol{W} \boldsymbol{n}$ is correct. It retrieves the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$.  Thanks for trying to provide an indirect answer. I didn't think that it would be that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming for instance $n_1\ne0$ (the reasoning if $n_2\ne0$ is similar), $v$ is a solution of
$$\forall i,j\in\{1,2\},\quad v_in_j=W_{i,j}$$
iff:
$$\forall i\in\{1,2\},\quad v_i=\frac{W_{i,1}}{n_1}\text{ and }\frac{W_{i,1}}{n_1}n_2=W_{i,2},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\forall i\in\{1,2\},\quad W_{i,1}n_2=W_{i,2}n_1\text{ and }(n_1^2+n_2^2)v_i=W_{i,1}n_1+W_{i,2}n_2.$$
A necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a solution $v$ is therefore $$\forall i\in\{1,2\},\quad W_{i,1}n_2=W_{i,2}n_1,$$
and that solution is then unique, given by
$$v=\frac1{\|n\|^2}Wn.$$

Alternative method: if $$v\otimes n=W$$
then (by direct computation)
$$\forall i\in\{1,2\},\quad W_{i,1}n_2=W_{i,2}n_1\text{ and }(n_1^2+n_2^2)v_i=W_{i,1}n_1+W_{i,2}n_2,$$
and the converse can also be checked by direct computation.